# mongodb logfile entries 'end connection'

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB 2.6.0 running on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. The database is in a replication set with just one node so far. After running for about 3 weeks my application which uses the mongodb hanged. At this excat time I found following log entries in mongodb.log:

```
2014-08-17T06:41:27.408+0200 [clientcursormon]  connections:8
2014-08-17T06:41:27.408+0200 [clientcursormon]  replication threads:32
2014-08-17T06:45:20.863+0200 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:40189 (7 connections now open)
2014-08-17T06:45:20.863+0200 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:40188 (7 connections now open)
2014-08-17T06:45:20.866+0200 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:40339 (5 connections now open)
2014-08-17T06:45:20.866+0200 [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:60176 (4 connections now open)
2014-08-17T06:45:20.866+0200 [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:60178 (3 connections now open)
2014-08-17T06:45:20.867+0200 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:51651 (2 connections now open)
2014-08-17T06:46:27.451+0200 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:745 virt:51196
2014-08-17T06:46:27.451+0200 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):50664
2014-08-17T06:46:27.451+0200 [clientcursormon]  connections:2
2014-08-17T06:46:27.451+0200 [clientcursormon]  replication threads:32
```

My question is: Is the 'end connection' initiated by the client or the server here?
Immediately after these lines, the mongodb server restarted. The next lines are on a new logfile:

```
2014-08-17T06:47:02.674+0200 [signalProcessingThread] pid=1090 port=27017 64-bit host=efr02
2014-08-17T06:47:02.674+0200 [signalProcessingThread] db version v2.6.0
2014-08-17T06:47:02.674+0200 [signalProcessingThread] git version: 1c1c76aeca21c5983dc178920f5052c298db616c
2014-08-17T06:47:02.674+0200 [signalProcessingThread] build info: Linux build14.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-08-17T06:47:02.674+0200 [signalProcessingThread] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-08-17T06:47:02.674+0200 [signalProcessingThread] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", processManagement: { pidFilePath: "/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, replication: { replSet: "rs_ipzr_db" }, storage: { dbPath: "/mongodata" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2014-08-17T06:51:27.488+0200 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:745 virt:51196
```

That looks like a restart or am I wrong?
I don't know, who initiated that restart nor do I find an entry in the local.db/startup_log. There the last entry is from July 23.

Could anyone please point me to the right direction, where to find relevant information for this behaviour?

Comment: It does look like a server startup in the second log but I don't see anything that looks like an error in either log excerpt. Is that everything in the logs from around that time? Is there anything in the system logs?

Comment: The system logs don't show any special events around that time. Also, the mongodb server normally has a line *** Server Restart *** for a normal restart, which is missing here. What about the 'end connection' lines: Are they initiated by the server or the client?